# CSS link href path with '/' in ejs file

Tags: css, node.js, http, express, ejs

pic 1 : set up express.static for public folder

pic 2 : set up href="/app.css" in post.ejs

pic 3 : result

I tried using **/app.css** and  **app.css** in post.ejs

the results are the same as the third picture

Does that mean after I set up

**app.use(express.static("public"));**

in app.js then the root path for static file will be **/public**?

And therefore

**absolute path**  /app.css and

**relative path**  app.css

are the same?

thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As your setting, public is the root folder. 
You can call app.css by 2 ways, "app.css" and "/app.css". They both get the file app.css in current root folder -> I think they are same.